# #linkedin I'm trying too make a CRM system for my work. Is it possible to get Linkdin API access? Since there's authorization

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to write a program that import/export information from Excel and into Linkdin.

Some of the code have been with help of chat... Chat says it needs authorization in terms of service may violate their policies.

since...

> "LinkedIn does not provide a public API that allows direct access to user profile data for personal use"

I tried contacting Linkind, but questions like this was passed on to stack overflow.

Since I don't want to violate their policies, I will try it here.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to violate their policies, you can't do anything. But if you want to be courageous, and use some browser automation tools, you can for sure do it.